# Google Cloud API to get which SSL Policy being attached to Load balancer

Tags: c#, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, gcp-api

I have an web application that need to access to google cloud and capture all details of load balancer
Some basic information are fine; I can get it.
However, it looks like there is no API to capture LB's [Front end] details; so that I can not get the attached SSL Policy name.
I tried to find API to capture the SSL policy details to get the [In use by] property but looks like the same that no API to call.

I do not know if instead of the objects them self (LB;SSL Policy) there is any other types of APIs to get relationships between them ?

Is there any idea about this please .?

Thank you very much.!!

I tried look through Google API Docs